# ASP.NET MVC3 Html.Raw changing absolute URLs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and the helper @Html.Raw in my view.

I'm passing it some HTML markup that I have stored in a database.  The markup contains some URLs that point to other places on my site.  For example http://www.foo.fom/events.  These data are forum posts, so the page they're displayed on has the form http://www.foo.com/forums/thread/42/slug.

However, when the page is rendered, the saved URLs are rendered in modified form as:

http://www.foo.com/forums/thread/42/events/

This only happens for URLs on my site.  If the URL points to some external site, it is unchanged.

I have verified that what I'm passing into @Html.Raw is the correct URL (http://www.foo.com/events).  Why is it getting changed as the page is rendered?  Is there an easy way to disable this "feature"?

Here's my code for displaying the markup:

```
<div>
        @Html.Raw(post.Body)
</div>
```

and here's the controller code that genrates the page data:

```
var post = _forumRepository.GetPostById(id)

var model = new ForumPostView()
{
    Body = post.Body,
    PostDate = post.DatePosted,
    PostedBy = post.Author,
    PostId = post.Id
};

return View(model);
```

I have verified via debugger that the exact URL in the post.Body before being passed back to the View is of the form "http://www.foo.com/events"  (no trailing slash).  I have also verified via debugger that the value is unchanged before it is passed into @Html.Raw.

Comment: Show us your actual code.  Html.Raw does not do any Url remapping, so it is something else that is doing it.

Comment: As @Mystere notes, `Html.Raw` does not manipulate your data.  Please show us the exact contents of `post.Body` -- perhaps write it to a file so we know precisely what that data is.

Comment: That's somewhat odd.  How are you setting "post" in your view?  Shouldn't that be Model.Body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the urls that are pointing to other pages on your site are non-absolute.  Are you **certain** they start with a `/` or `http`?  If not, it's behaving exactly as it's supposed and treating them like relative urls -- and thus appending them to the current url.

(`Html.Raw` will not manipulate the string, so it's not at fault here)

Also, it wouldn't hurt to show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

No, in fact I am an idiot.  The URLs were indeed stored in relative form without a leading /, which is why they ended up being relative to the current page.  The text displayed was absolute, which is what I saw when I looked at the db.  That's what I get for debugging on a few hours' sleep ;)

Comment: Heh, has happened to us all.  :)   Thanks for reporting back!